# How can i get a list of all special methods available?

Tags: python, django

Special methods are for example (in Django):

```
def __wrapper__
def __deepcopy__
def __mod__
def __cmp__
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: What do you want? What's the difference between Django's and Python's reserved words? Do you just want a list of Python's reserved words?

Comment: i'm sorry,this is my highest level of write english,i think you have to use your imagination of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of special method names is [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), but it's not an exhaustive of magic names -- for example, methods `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` are mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html?highlight=__copy__) instead, the `__all__` variable is [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package), class attributes such as `__name__`, `__bases__`, etc are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__name__#class.__name__), and so on.  I don't know of any single authoritative list of all such names defined in any given release of the language.

However, if you want to check on any single given special name, say `__foo__`, just search for it in the "Quick search" box of the Python docs (any of the above URLs will do!) -- this way you will find it if it's officially part of the language, and if you **don't** find it you'll know it is a mistaken usage on the part of some package or framework that's violating the language's conventions.

Answer (score 9):

To print Python's reserved words just use

```
>>> import keyword
>>> print(keyword.kwlist)
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue',
'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global',
'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass',
'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

To read an explanation of special object methods of Python, [read the manual](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) or [Dive into Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames).

Another snippet you can use is

```
>>> [method for method in dir(str) if method[:2]=='__']
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', 
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', 
'__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', 
'__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

to see all the built in special methods of the `str` class.

Comment: Note that `dir()` does not shows attributes on parent classes. For example, `str.__mro__` is not included in your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can find most of them here: http://docs.python.org/genindex-all.html#_

identifiers with 2 leading+2 trailing underscores are of course reserved for [special method names](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers). Although it is possible to define such identifiers now, may not be the case in future. __deepcopy__, __mod__, and __cmp__ are all special methods built into python that user classes can override to implement class-specific functionality.

Comment: You will always be able to define `__something__` identifiers unless the language is redefined. You have to be aware though that you might be overwriting the variable identification of an existing special method name.

Comment: well the doc says "applications should not expect to define names using this convention," which implies the behavior might as well be undefined (i.e., it could work, it could fail subtly, could blow up in a future version, etc.)....